# webClient DownloadData socket exception

Tags: c#, azure, azure-web-app-service

I use webClient.DownloadData to download a file from Google Drive from Azure website, I get the error:

```
SocketException An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions 74.125.128.102:80
    at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)
```

Code:

```
using (var webClient = new WebClient())
                {
                    pdf = webClient.DownloadData("drive.google.com/something.pdf");
                }
```

It works localy but not azure.

I am using Azure Websites free for testing purpose.

Comment: I want to process the file.

Comment: Is the file publicly available?

Comment: yes it is publicly available.

Comment: I don't know how it works in Azure Websites but in Azure Virtual Machines you may have to configure your instance from Azure website (section Endpoints / Rules / Ports). Have a look at the configuration of your instance, there should be a similar tab for this

Comment: Which code line is throwing the exception? `DownloadData` doesn't throw this kind of exceptions?